# Consumindo API com NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, google-maps-api-3

Estou desenvolvendo como projetos de estudos uma API que consome dados da API do Google. Quero que minha API que recebe diversos dados da API do Google disponibilize apenas os dados de Cidade e Estado para as aplicações que venham a utilizar minha API.

Como posso trabalhar para extrair apenas esses dados do JSON que recebo da API do Google? Não tenho ideia de como faze-lo já olhei diversos tutoriais no You Tube mas não consigo.

Segue abaixo o meu código e a resposta que minha API entrega ao cliente.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Comment: não cole imagens, coloque o código em texto na pergunta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
//Parsea os dados
const jsonParse = await JSON.parse(response.data)

//Acessando Propriedades do Json Retornado
res.json(jsonParse['results'][0])

//Ou se quiser acessar mais propriedades do json pode fazer desta forma
res.json(jsonParse['results'][0]['address_components'])
```

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado me ajudou D+